# SQL 2008 Report Manager not working

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs

I have a SQL 2008 developer edition with SSRS and the report manager is only available from the local machine. If I try to access it from any other machine I get challenged for my domain u/name and pwd 3 times and then the screen stays blank.

I have made changes to some config files (originals copied out) in order to get a 3rd party application to run but that is now uninstalled and the config files are all back to vanilla (originals copied back in)

I feel its something to do with authentication but am stuck ...

any suggestions welcomed

Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just stumbled on the answer.

I changed the Report Server Service Account to use the built-in Local System account and its all accessible from remote browsers.

Anyone any ideas why?